# Как выровнять строки при flex flex-wrap wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Если высота элемента становится больше, то он получается выше чем остальные элементы на той же строке. 
И важно чтобы эти элементы выводились по центру страницы.

https://jsfiddle.net/z9qp0n41/9/

Если поставить 
`align-items: baseline;`
у `.container`

то элементы выравниваются, но прилипают к верху родителя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как выводить элементы по центру и при этом чтобы элементы каждой строки были выравнены по baseline?

Comment: `align-items:center` отцентрирует flex-элементы по вертикали (если я правильно понял проблему).

Comment: ну как бы fle x то выравнивает верно ..просто у вас в одном блоке есть текст